# Is it possible install Windows phone sdk on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-phone, windows-server-2012, build-server

According to [system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) I can install SDK only on Windows 8 machine *(I need support Windows Phone 8 platform too)*.

I want to create build server for WP applications, so can I use Windows Server for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install WP SDK on my Windows Server 2012 without any problems. 
Did you have any troubles?

PS. But as I know not all CPU are compatible.

Comment: Which version of the SDK you're talking about? Is it WP8 or WP7?

Comment: @Agent_L, about WP8 SDK. As I know WP8 SDK includes WP7 SDK